# Implementation of Reddit,StumbleUpon,del.icio.us and Digg in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know, Is it possible to integrate  Reddit, StumbleUpon, del.icio.us and Digg in iPhone app? I have to implement all this in my iPhone app. Please give me the some any example link  about all these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Delicious you can use [sharKit](http://getsharekit.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Digg has a REST API clearly documented here: http://developers.digg.com/documentation